# An edit made to a post of mine includes a fix to a spelling mistake contained within a quote block, should I edit it to add the mistake back in?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I logged in this morning to find a notification about suggested edit on a post of mine (which by this point had already been approved): https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16492653. Ignoring the fact that the edit itself is mostly meaningless, the edit itself corrected a spelling mistake within a quote.

The quote itself is from [this GitHub repository's readme](https://github.com/mdo/css-perf#how-testing-is-done) and almost 2 years on the spelling mistake is still present:

> [image]

At first I completely ignored the change, but now I've got to thinking: should I edit the post to re-introduce the spelling error (perhaps with a "[sic]")?

Comment: Why? Does the spelling mistake have a impact on the issue itself? If not then why not correct it, just because it's wrong on another site doesn't mean it should be here.

Comment: Preserving the typo in the quote do not seem to add any value at all, IMO.

Comment: @Epodax the problem I see is that where this is a quote it's not really my place to modify the content. My answer no longer directly quotes the resource and this to me somewhat invalidates the quote - especially as there's no mention that the quote has been tampered with in any way.

Comment: Personally, I don't feel that by correcting a typo you are putting words in someone's mouth. Even more so a github repo. Are you going to update your quote if someone makes a PR to fix that typo or change the text of the quote?

Comment: @yivi if it had indeed changed then yes, an edit would make a lot of sense. It wouldn't matter if it wasn't edited though because the resource itself *should* include an indication of when it was modified (which would occur after the quote was last modified in the answer).

Comment: I do think spelling mistakes should be fixed, even when citing off-site resources. How about adding a `<sup>1</sup>` when you (or any editor) start citing and at the end of the answer: `<sup>1. fixed minor spelling issues</sup>`, when applicable?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I get your point but I just feel that it's such a minor thing that it's hardly worth reverting the edit for. Had the spelling mistake been on purpose or had any form of impact or relation to the issue, then it would be another matter completely. And I honestly don't feel it's a issue that you're not "directly quoting" the text when the quoted text properly would be fixed if the original author was made aware / could be bothered to do so.

Comment: It's worth fixing because right now the quotation is wrong. You're not supposed to fix spelling and grammar in quotations, not without indicating that something's changed. Honestly, I'd just rollback the edit; it didn't really improve anything and shouldn't have been approved.

Comment: Typo fixed in [repo](https://github.com/mdo/css-perf#how-testing-is-done).  :)

Comment: @yivi all's well that ends well.

Comment: I strongly feel a quote should accurately reflect what's in the original, but this is a quote of a GitHub repo. Submit a Pull Request with the corrected spelling, so it ends up being correct both places. If the pull request doesn't get applied in a reasonable time, then revert the edit on SO (or note it as described in BoltClock♦'s answer). There have been lots of times where I've found mistakes in original content while writing an answer, where I can correct the original content. I've then done so and quoted the correct information. In this instance, the GitHub repo has already been changed.

Comment: Now that the typo has been fixed, can we stop fixating on the fact that the specific source in question is a GitHub repo? I'm not going to question @Makyen's claim that they've been able to correct content on other sites "lots of times", but let's not take for granted the fact that 99.99% of the web isn't as freely editable as Stack Overflow, and allowances have to be made in situations where, as Makyen mentioned, errata submissions don't get addressed in a reasonable amount of time, or at all.

Comment: @BoltClock, In your answer, you covered well what to do wrt. the 99.99% of the web which is, at best, difficult to change. I was pointing out that correcting the source is *possible* and *desirable* (particularly for technical inaccuracies). How easy that is, varies quite a bit. If you don't include quotes from MDN documentation (openly editable) and GitHub repos, then my "lots" goes down to "sometimes". For MDN, it's any time I've seen an error, which get it to "lots". Tech people usually want things correct, but getting info to them, and them being permitted to change it, is often difficult.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Personally (I'm not speaking in authority here), I strongly favor preserving the integrity of quotations, warts and all. If I notice a spelling error when quoting a source within my own answer, I will either mark it with "[sic]" or indicate that I have changed it by enclosing the changed text in square brackets. In your case, it would be "([currently] 10.9.1)".

If I see an answer with a spelling error in a quotation, assuming the answerer is indeed quoting someone else (as opposed to misusing quotation formatting with original text for example), I assume that the spelling error is in the original text and *leave it alone*. I don't even add "[sic]" to their quotation, because I consider that a deviation from the answerer's intent, even if I don't see it as a violation of the quotation's integrity strictly speaking.

But if I see an answer that's already been edited in such a way as to dirty a quotation... I wouldn't roll it back unless the edit changes the meaning of the quoted text. Otherwise I'd just be kicking up a fuss.

But in this case, it's your answer. As the owner of your answer you are free to decide if you want to preserve the integrity of the quotation by reintroducing the spelling error with a "[sic]", though I'd actually recommend the "([currently] 10.9.1)" alternative here since as others mentioned the spelling error doesn't particularly impact the issue itself.

I do maintain my position that it is unreasonable to edit a quotation with no indication that anything was changed, *even if the edits are minor* (others may disagree of course), and I strongly encourage others to avoid editing quoted text in other people's answers.

Comment: \*re-reads first paragraph, using loud, authoritative tone\*

Comment: @CodyGray and the last, changing "encourage" to "demand".

Comment: @EMBarbosa: *You'd better pray I don't catch you editing quotes in other people's answers, or so help me I will mod you so hard*

Comment: Yeah, or better yet, encourage to fix any issue they see whenever on the site or *elsewhere*.